# Identify when DrawerLayout scroll is positioned at last item in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a `DrawerLayout` side menu with 15 items. I want to know when the user scrolls the side menu and reached the last item of side menu. ie., I want to do an action when user has scrolled to the 15th item of the side menu. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using recycler view or list view to show drawer items.so just check your item index with size of arraylist like

if(position == myList.size()-1){/*lastItem*/}